# Creating a custom Customer attribute through module upgrade (UpgradeData.php)

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.2

As title says, i'm having troubles at creating new customers attribute when upgrading one of my modules.

I've created the UpgradeData.php file under `/app/code/vendor/modulename/Setup/UpgradeData.php` with the current code:

```
namespace Ucs\CustomerAttribute\Setup;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface{

private $customerSetupFactory;

public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){

    $setup->startSetup();

    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6') < 0) {

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'nome_azienda', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Nome azienda',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'nome_azienda')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();


        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'codice_univoco', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Codice Univoco',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'codice_univoco')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();


    }
}
}
```

in short, it needs to create 2 new text (varchar) attributes. My `module.xml` has 
`setup_version="1.0.5"  schema_version="1.0.5"` so it should enter the `version_compare` condition and create the attribute, but, after running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` it doesn't work. Even by removing that "if" condition no attributes are created. If i check in the `setup_module` table, the `setup_version` and `schema_version` change correctly with the version in the `module.xml`. It looks like for some reason the `UpgradeData.php` does not get executed at all (even trying to log a string into a log file doesn't write anything). Other log files under `..../var/log/` show no errors or warnings. With this module i have already created OTHER custom Customer attributes with the `installData.php` file with no issues at all.

I have no idea what to do, can't really understand what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Small update I've tried to log some text with the native LoggerInterface and nothing gets logged. Looks like the script does not get executed

Comment: Have you included registration.php for the module
?

Comment: @Andrew yes, the module was installed correctly a few months ago and it always worked

Answer (score 0):

You can check it the below links:

1. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/254790/upgradedata-to-add-a-custom-customer-attribute-is-not-working-in-magento2
2. https://github.com/mundipagg/magento2/blob/master/Setup/UpgradeData.php

Comment: I had already tried the first link, even by checking the code in the second link is not working. I've tried to log some text with the native LoggerInterface and nothing gets logged. Looks like the script does not get executed